# Sending Data Between Arduino Nano and D1 Mini

Tags: serial, esp8266, arduino-nano, data

I am sending data from Arduino Nano to D1 Mini,

*Transmitter is Arduino Nano*

**Transmitter Code:**

```
#include <DES.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial link(2, 3); // Rx, Tx
DES des;
byte in[8];
String  input;
char text[20];
char charVal[6];
char buf[30];
void setup() {
  link.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Hello! Pleace Enter Your Data to Encrypt");
}
void tdesTest() {
  byte out[8];
  byte key[] = {
    0x3b, 0x38, 0x98, 0x37, 0x15, 0x20, 0xf7, 0x5e, // key A
    0x92, 0x2f, 0xb5, 0x10, 0xc7, 0x1f, 0x43, 0x6e, // key B
    0x3b, 0x38, 0x98, 0x37, 0x15, 0x20, 0xf7, 0x5e, // key C (in this case A)
  };
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("====== Triple-DES test ======");
  //encrypt
  Serial.print("Encrypt...");
  unsigned long time = micros();
  des.tripleEncrypt(out, in, key);
  time = micros() - time;
  Serial.print("done. (");
  Serial.print(time);
  Serial.println(" micros)");
  delay(10000);
  printArray(out, link);
  link.write(out, 9);
  delay(2000);
  //decrypt
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    in[i] = out[i];
  }
  Serial.print("Decrypt...");
  time = micros();
  des.tripleDecrypt(out, in, key);
  time = micros() - time;
  Serial.print("done. (");
  Serial.print(time);
  Serial.println(" micros)");
  printArray(out);
  delay(2000);
}
//passing output and Print
void printArray(byte output[], Print& serial)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    if (output[i] < 0x10)
    {
      Serial.print("0");
    }
    Serial.print(output[i], HEX);
    Serial.print(" ");
    delay(100);
  }
  
  Serial.println();
}
//printing output without link pass
void printArray(byte output[])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    if (output[i] < 0x10)
    {
      Serial.print("0");
    }
    Serial.print(output[i], HEX);
    Serial.print(" ");
    delay(100);
  }
  Serial.println();
}
void userdata() {
  Serial.println("Sending User Data");
  byte user[] = {0x31,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30};
  printArray(user, link);
  link.write(user, 9);
  delay(100);
  tdesTest();
  
}
void loop() {
  while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    String  input = Serial.readString(); // read the incoming data as string
    memset(in, 0, 9); // Erase the contents of in[]
    input.toCharArray((char *)in, 9); // Copy up to 8 bytes from the string
    
    userdata();
  }
}
```

And receiving same from *D1 Mini (ESP8266)*

**Receiver Code:**

```
//Receiver code
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial link(4, 0); // Rx, Tx

byte greenLED = 13;
byte cString[8];
byte chPos;
byte ch;
byte out[8];
String hexstring = "";


void setup()
{
  link.begin(9600); //setup software serial
  Serial.begin(9600);    //setup serial monitor
  pinMode(greenLED, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{

  while (link.available() > 0)
  {
    ESP.wdtDisable(); // This helps th avoid not reciving data after second try 


    //read incoming char by char:
    ch = link.read();
    cString[chPos] = ch;
    chPos++;


    digitalWrite(greenLED, HIGH); //flash led to show data is arriving
    delay(20);
    digitalWrite(greenLED, LOW);

  }
  if (ch != 0)
  {
    printArray(cString);
    ESP.wdtEnable(1);
    Serial.flush();
    cString[chPos] = 0; //terminate cString
    chPos = 0;
  }


}

//printing output
void printArray(byte output[])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    if (output[i] < 0x10)
    {
      Serial.print("0");
    }
    Serial.print(output[i], HEX);
    hexstring += String(output[i], HEX);
    Serial.print(" ");
    delay(100);

  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Your String Sir:");
  Serial.print(hexstring);
  Serial.println();
  ch = 0; // Avoid printing 0s when no data is recived
  hexstring = ""; //Clear the memeory of hexstring
}
```

**In Receiver I am receiving data as below:**

[image]

I want to get data in Single Stream to receiver *as Example: 31 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 7E B5 2D 4D 93 CB 08 BA* or in receiver join two streams in to a single stream,

**On Side Note:**
1st Part is Plain Data and 2nd Part will be Encrypted Data

Could anyone please help..

Comment: Can't you concat 2 strings? If you would a white space between each byte just concatenate a space. Trivial answer but I'm not sure which your core question is.

Comment: How to do that? Transmitter sends two char streams,

Comment: Since I don't think concat will work

Comment: Why not? You calculate `hexstring`, which can be concat to the next one.

Comment: Could you share me how in my receiver code ?

Comment: @fabianoriccardi **Still Same** Could you help me to fix the issue.

Comment: Accidently got deleted previous comment

Comment: Actually I don't know how to help you: I can explain what you should do, but I will not write code since I cannot test it.

Comment: Yes, Please help me, I will test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed Get it Working:

Change the Transmitter Code to Cascade Two Char Streams Before Sending:

**Transmitter Code:**

```
#include <DES.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial link(2, 3); // Rx, Tx
DES des;
byte in[8];
String  input;


void setup() {
  link.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Hello! Pleace Enter Your Data to Encrypt");

}

//passing output and Print
void printArray(byte output[], Print& serial)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    if (output[i] < 0x10)
    {
      Serial.print("0");

    }
    Serial.print(output[i], HEX);
    Serial.print(" ");
    delay(100);


  }

  Serial.println();

}
//printing output without link pass
void printArray(byte output[])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    if (output[i] < 0x10)
    {
      Serial.print("0");

    }
    Serial.print(output[i], HEX);
    Serial.print(" ");
    delay(100);

  }
  Serial.println();
}

void userdata_and_Encrypt() {
  Serial.println("Sending User Data");
  byte username[] = {0x31, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30};
  printArray(username, link);
  byte username_data = (username, 9);
  delay(100);

  byte out[8];
  byte key[] = {
    0x3b, 0x38, 0x98, 0x37, 0x15, 0x20, 0xf7, 0x5e, // key A
    0x92, 0x2f, 0xb5, 0x10, 0xc7, 0x1f, 0x43, 0x6e, // key B
    0x3b, 0x38, 0x98, 0x37, 0x15, 0x20, 0xf7, 0x5e, // key C (in this case A)
  };

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("====== Triple-DES test ======");
  //encrypt
  Serial.print("Encrypt...");
  unsigned long time = micros();
  des.tripleEncrypt(out, in, key);
  time = micros() - time;
  Serial.print("done. (");
  Serial.print(time);
  Serial.println(" micros)");
  delay(100);
  printArray(out, link);
  byte password_data = (out, 9);
  delay(100);
  byte data_stream = username_data + password_data; 
  printArray(data_stream, link);
  link.write(out, 17);

  //decrypt
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    in[i] = out[i];
  }
  Serial.print("Decrypt...");
  time = micros();
  des.tripleDecrypt(out, in, key);
  time = micros() - time;
  Serial.print("done. (");
  Serial.print(time);
  Serial.println(" micros)");
  printArray(out);
  delay(100);

}

void loop() {

  while (Serial.available() > 0) {

    String  input = Serial.readString(); // read the incoming data as string
    memset(in, 0, 9); // Erase the contents of in[]
    input.toCharArray((char *)in, 9); // Copy up to 8 bytes from the string

    userdata_and_Encrypt();

  }
}
```

Receiver Code to Accept 16 Bytes

**Receiver Code:**

```
//Receiver code
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial link(4, 0); // Rx, Tx

byte greenLED = 13;
byte cString[8];
byte chPos;
byte ch;
byte out[8];
String hexstring = "";
static String data = "";


void setup()
{
  link.begin(9600); //setup software serial
  Serial.begin(9600);    //setup serial monitor
  pinMode(greenLED, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{

  while (link.available() > 0)
  {
    ESP.wdtDisable(); // This helps th avoid not reciving data after second try


    //read incoming char by char:
    ch = link.read();
    cString[chPos] = ch;
    chPos++;


    digitalWrite(greenLED, HIGH); //flash led to show data is arriving
    delay(20);
    digitalWrite(greenLED, LOW);

  }
  if (ch != 0)
  {
    printArray(cString);
    ESP.wdtEnable(1);
    Serial.flush();
    cString[chPos] = 0; //terminate cString
    chPos = 0;
  }


}

//printing output
void printArray(byte output[])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
  {
    if (output[i] < 0x10)
    {
      Serial.print("0");
    }
    Serial.print(output[i], HEX);
    hexstring += String(output[i], HEX);
    Serial.print(" ");
    delay(100);



  }
  Serial.println();


  Serial.println("Your String Sir:");
  Serial.println(hexstring);




  Serial.println();
  ch = 0; // Avoid printing 0s when no data is recived
  hexstring = ""; //Clear the memeory of hexstring
}
```

**Working Output:**

[image]